# Winged Serpent God / Quetzalcoatl Fantasy Series

Tags: story-identification

I have a brain worm -- I am trying to think of a book series, what I can remember is:

In the late 80's early 90s I read a fantasy series as a young adult that involved a battle between a winged serpent / quetzalcoatl god and his nemesis.

To my recollection the main protagonists were on some kind of quest for the winged serpent god while being chased or followed by the nemesis god's agents.

I recall that in the final book they basically call out both gods as their war is destroying everything else.

I think this was part of a series made up of 2-4 books.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [Maztica](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Maztica) Trilogy by Douglas Niles?   There is a winged serpent deity (Qotal) and his enemy/nemesis - the God Zaltec.
It's basically a Forgotten Realms retelling of the Spanish conquistadores and the Aztec Empire in South America.

Qotal has not been seen for some centuries before the start of the trilogy and some of the story does include a quest to find him to do battle with his brother.

As a trilogy it fits in with your recollection of the number of books